# Track push notifications and log them

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications

For a project I’d like to track some specific iOS/Android apps and log their Pushes into my db.

I’m advanced with web scraping and db logging, but I have no idea how to extract information about new pushes from iOS/Android.

What would be the best/easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i have used to track push notification :

```
public class TrackNotification extends NotificationListenerService {


@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);

    //your code stuff
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);

    //your code stuff
}
```

}

In manifest :

```
 <service android:name=".Test"
        android:label="Test"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Thats for your own app, right? I’d like to track notifications of _other_ apps :)